# How are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$ related if $B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}O&A\\A&O\end{smallmatrix}\right]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Given matrix  $$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&b\\b&a&b\\b&b&a \end{bmatrix}$$
and matrix $$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&a&b&b\\0&0&0&b&a&b\\0&0&0&b&b&a\\a&b&b&0&0&0\\b&a&b&0&0&0\\b&b&a&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
I want to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $B$, and I know the eigenvalues of $A$ are $(a-b)$ and $(a+2b)$, and the corresponding eigenvectors are $(-1,1,0)$, $(-1,0,1)$, $(1,1,1)$. I can calculate $B$ in the normal way but it seems that there should be some shortcuts, so is there any relation between $A$ and $B$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to see that $\chi_B(X)=\chi_{A^2}(X^2)$ at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The larger matrix $B$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of $S=\binom{0~1}{1~0}$ and $A$. Since $S$ is diagonalisable with eigenvalues $-1,1$, then the eigenvalues of $B$ are $\pm\lambda_i$ where $\lambda_i$ runs through the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&A\\ A&0 \end{bmatrix}$ has an eigenpair $(\lambda$, $\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y \end{bmatrix})$ (note that $x$ and $y$ are row vectors).
We have
$
Ax=\lambda y
$ and $Ay = \lambda x$.
Therefore $A^2 x = A (Ax) = \lambda A y = \lambda^2 x$.
We conclude that $(\lambda^2,x)$ is an eigenpair of $A^2$.

In your case $A$ is of full rank. Therefore all eigenpairs of $A^2$ can be generated by those of $A$ (I'll leave it to you), i.e., either $(\lambda,x)$ or $(-\lambda,x)$ is an eigenpair of $A$.

---

In brief, you get that if  $(\lambda$, $\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y \end{bmatrix})$ is an eigenpair of $B$, then either $(\lambda,x)$ or $(-\lambda,x)$ is an eigenpair of $A$.